# React Router v6 and React.lazy not working correctly, throwing an error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Am refactoring my React application and have upgrade from React Router v5 to v6, seeing this error with a very simple `React.lazy()` call:

```sh
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, _payload, _init}).
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

```js
import React, { lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Pizzas = () => lazy(() => import('./Components/Pizzas'));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Pizzas />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And the `Pizzas` component is just:

```js
export const Pizzas = () => <div>Pizzas...</div>;
```

Now, if I change it over to this, it works just fine:

```js
import { Pizzas } from './Components/Pizzas';
```

... And the component renders just fine. It's a bit of a strange one and I have been searching for solutions with React Router v6 for an hour or so now to no avail. I'm using Create React App as well for reference.

#### Dependencies (package.json)

```json
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/css": "^11.1.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is *Typo*: It should be `const Pizzas = lazy(() => import('./Components/Pizzas'));`

Comment: @AjeetShah Oh my, thank you haha!

Answer (score 0):

you have to export the component as default for instance

```
export default const Pizzas = () => <div>Pizzas...</div>;
```

to be able to import this way

```
const Pizzas = () => lazy(() => import('./Components/Pizzas'));
```